# handling session with spring mvc

Tags: spring

Actually i am setting the attributes which are getting from bean class in modelandveiw method and trying to get that attribute in other modelandveiw method  method but getting null values in

rs.getAttribute("customerId")

. Please help me.

```
  @RequestMapping(value ="/insert",method= RequestMethod.Post)

   public ModelAndView inserData(@ModelAttribute SavingBean savingBean,HttpServletRequest rs) {

  HttpSession session = rs.getSession();

     if (savingBean != null)
     SavingBean saving =  persionalService.insertData(savingBean);

    int a =  saving.getCustomerId();

     rs.setAttribute("customerId",a );


  System.out.println(saving.getDisgnProf());

   List<SavingBean> list = new ArrayList<SavingBean>();
   list.add(saving);

  return new ModelAndView("welcome","list", list);



 }



   @RequestMapping(value ="/insertdata",method= RequestMethod.Post)

public ModelAndView check (@ModelAttribute SavingBean savingBean,HttpServletRequest rs) {


     System.out.println(savingBean.getFirstName());

    HttpSession session = rs.getSession();



  System.out.println("abhishek" + rs.getAttribute("customerId"));



 return null ;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting or getting anything from the session in this code. You're putting and getting attributes from `rs`, and `rs` is the request, not the session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are putting it in the request rs, put it in session instead and you vill se it